# SQL. Checking condition and marking in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

Here is my PEOPLE table where I store name, surname, DOB (date of birth) and some other data. In a new query I need to add additional column with the condition for people with the same Name & Surname combination. Here is the condition:

- Go through each group of people with the same Name & Surname combinations, in additional field mark those, whose DOB is not maximum and not minimum (compared only to same Name & Surname)
- If there is only 1 or 2 occurrences of same Name & Surname, mark them anyway

[image]

Here is the result of a query

[image]

Explanation:

- John Doe marked as met only once
- Tom Taylor marked as met only twice
- Alice Smith and Bob Brown marked everywhere except records with min and max DOB

**Please help to form SQL query for the desired output.** Here is my understanding (guessing)

- Get list of unique Name&Surname pairs, ( where occurrences >2 ??? )
- For each unique pair find rows with min and max DOB (avoid them)
- In a new CheckBox column mark those that are left (not extremum)

Comment: Another approach I can think of is:
Select rows with MIN and MAX DOB where occurrences of unique Name&Surname > 2, avoid them, mark everything else

Answer (score 1):

First `group by name, surname` to get the number of occurrences and min and max dob of each name and surname and join the results to the table.
With a CASE statement apply the conditions:

```
select 
  p.*,
  case  
    when g.counter in (1, 2) then 'mark'
    else case
      when p.dob not in (g.mindob, g.maxdob) then 'mark' 
    end
  end Checkbox
from peaople inner join (
  select 
    name, surname,
    count(*) counter,
    min(dob) mindob,
    max(dob) maxdob
  from people
  group by name, surname
) g on g.name = p.name and g.surname = p.surname
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions in MySQL 8+:

```
select p.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by name, surname) <= 2
             then 'mark'
             when row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by dob) > 1 and
                  row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by dob desc) > 1
             then 'mark'
        end) as checkbox
from people p;
```

Note:  If there are duplicates for the earliest or latest birthdate, this only excludes one of them.  If you want to exclude all of them, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.